# CodeIgniter: Join more than 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have five tables:

1. `Bill`: no(pk),date, time, total
2. `BillOrderRelation`: no(fk), order_id(fk)
3. `Order`: order_id(pk), menu_id(fk), quantities, total
4. `Menu`: menu_id(pk), category_id(fk), menu_name, stock, price
5. `Category`: category_id(pk), category_name, colour

In my case, I have to retrieve which menu that has a highest sales in one day range, 7 days range, and 30 days range.

I've already succeed retrieve those information, but i think it's too complicated. First I have to retrieve the date on Bill, and then find the order in BillOrderRelation, and then find the Menu, and find the Category name. It includes a lot of queries and complex way to do the summing stuff for the same menu.

My question is, is that possible to query all those table in one query to retrieve just menu.menu_name, order.quantities, order.total, category.name and it's included the sum stuff for the same menu retrieved?

I've already succeed make a query for three table without using time range like this..

```
SELECT 
    menu.menu_name as top_item, 
    SUM(order.quantities) AS count_sold, 
    SUM(order.total) AS amount, 
    category.nama AS categories 
FROM 
    menu, order, category 
WHERE 
    menu.mennu_id = bill.menu_id 
    AND category.category_id = menu.category_id 
GROUP BY 
    bill.menu_id, menu.menu_name, category.category_name 
ORDER BY 
    count_sold DESC
```

Is there any tricky way for the case above?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: aah thank you for telling me, i'll not using those syntax again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update for PostgreSQL*

I believe you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    m.menu_name AS top_item
    , c.name AS category
    , SUM(o.quantities) AS sum_quantity
    , SUM(o.total) AS sum_total
FROM
    menu m
JOIN
    category c
    ON c.category_id=m.category_id
JOIN
    order o
    ON o.menu_id=m.menu_id
JOIN
    billorderrelation bor
    ON bor.order_id=o.order_id
JOIN
    bill b
    ON b.no=bor.no
WHERE
    b.date >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 days')
GROUP BY
    m.menu_id
ORDER BY
    sum_quantity DESC
;
```

`CURRENT_DATE` allows you to get the current date (according to the timezone specified in your database). Read more:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Comment: Ah i got it. The answer is it's possible to join those table but i'm using postgresql and the date also in bill is string, is that possiible using some stuff like dat_sub and curdate?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a bill date string value?

Comment: @MagnificentGlitch It will be even better if you encapsulate the query inside  SQL View, and in your code you will be accessing like `SELECT * FROM view_order_report` and you will get all the field (ex. top_item, category, sum_quantity, sum_total)

Comment: @neutomatter 

Bill row example: 1 | 31-7-2017 | 11:59:18 | 100000

i was mentioned the column name in the question above. The date and the time are string

Comment: @JMS786 how can i do that? or is there any reference i can read?

Comment: Yes.. [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm)..

Comment: @JMS768 Thank's dude

Comment: i've changed the data type for date by the way, i'll try your suggest @neuromatter